# How to find the time complexity of modular multiplication?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

There are two number of length m bits. How do I prove that the complexity of modular multiplication of these two numbers is $O(m^2)$.

Comment: See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3360) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division) me[thod](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27808065/380772). ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

*Hello, welcome to crypto.SE.*

This is not cryptography, but I will answer it with a **simplified example to give you the intuition**. Lets consider $123 \times 456$.

```
    123
  x 456
  -----
    738
   615
+ 492
-------
  56088
```

Right ?

How did you get $738$? Obviously you did $6 \times 3 + 6 \times 20 + 6 \times 1$. Therefore you made 3 multiplications.
Should the first number be $m$ long, you would have had $m$ multiplications.
Because the second number is also $m$ long, you would have to do this $m$ times hence the $O(m^2)$.

---

From the **[Handbook of APPLIED CRYPTOGRAPHY](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)**, page 71

> Let $n$ be q positive integer. As before, the elements of $Z_n$ 
>   will be represented by the integers $\{0,1,2 ..., n-1 \}$.
>
> Observe that if $a,b \in Z_n$, then
>   $$(a+b)\mod n = \begin{cases}a+b, &\text{if}\ a + b < n\\
> a+b-n &\text{if}\ a + b \ge n\\ \end{cases}$$

Note that in term of bit complexity we are in $log(n)$

> Hence modular addition (and subtraction) can be performed without the need of a long division. **Modular multiplication** of $a$ and $b$ may be accomplished by **simply multiplying** $a$ and $b$ as integers, and then **taking the remainder of the result** after division by $n$.

Without any optimizations, note that taking the reminder is just applying at most $m$ subtraction of $m$.
Hence a modular multiplication is at most $2 \times m^2$ operations therefore $O(m^2)$ (and bitwise complexity $O(log^2(m))$).

Comment: The complexity that you've calculated is for long multiplication. Can you show how to find this for modular multiplication?

Comment: I updated the answer for the modular complexity.

Comment: Without multiplying the numbers and dividing by n to get remainder, we can find the remainder of two numbers separately and then take the modulus of the result. Is it more efficient than $O(m^2)$

Comment: But you assume that the numbers are in $Z_n$, hence your optimization does not really make sense. :/